# rectangle on image in Monodroid

Tags: image, xamarin.android, detection, rectangles, drawrectangle

I've been trying to draw a rectangle on to an image which is a face photo. Like face detection in photograph machines but coordinates of rectangle will be taken from server. Can anyone please help me about this problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to examine this https://gist.github.com/slodge/2927149 codes.